# General estimating equation with Tweedie distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution, tweedie

Does anyone know if one can use a Tweedie distribution in a general estimating equation model in R? I tried using the following data:

```
structure(list(focal = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), .Label = c("175", "203", 
"208", "226", "230", "259", "263", "273", "280", "291", "307", 
"308", "313", "318", "322", "323", "331", "335", "337", "340", 
"Jm", "Umm1g", "Umm1o", "Umm1p", "Umm1y", "Umm2g", "Umm2p", "Umm2y", 
"Umm3g", "Umm3p", "Umm4p"), class = "factor"), sexnn = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    groomingratio = c(NA, 0.333333333, NA, 0.352941176, 0.4, 
    1, 0.214285714, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.285714286, NA, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.318181818, 0.222222222, 0.111111111, 0.173913043, 
    0.333333333, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0.5, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.045454545, 
    1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.222222222, 0, 0.666666667, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0.5, 1, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, NA, 0.038461538, 1, 0, 0.052631579, 0.5, 0.333333333, 
    0, NA, 0, 0.236842105, 0.463414634, 0.266666667, 0.066666667, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.037037037, 0.5, 0.105263158, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 
    0.095238095, 0.125, 2, 0.475, 0.2, NA, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0.173913043, 
    0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    0.588235294, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0.1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0.111111111, 
    0.166666667, 0.666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857143, NA, 0.666666667, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 
    0.2, 0, 0.75, 0.333333333, NA, 0.25, 0, 0.625, NA, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.363636364, 0, NA, 0.25, 0, 0.105263158, 0, 0.166666667, 
    0, 0.5, 0.25, NA, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.181818182, 0.2, 0, 0, 
    0.285714286, 0, 0.066666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.181818182, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, NA, 0, 0.027777778, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0.368421053, 0.25, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, 0.2, 0.095238095, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.25, 0.666666667, 
    0.333333333, 0.222222222, 0.5, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0.5, NA, 0.2, 0, 0.05, 0.8, 0.4, NA, 0, 0.181818182, NA, 
    0, NA, NA, 0.25, 0.25, 0.125, NA, 0.333333333, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0.333333333, NA, 0.352941176, 0.4, 1, 
    0.214285714, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.285714286, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.318181818, 0.222222222, 0.111111111, 0.173913043, 
    0.333333333, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0.5, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.045454545, 
    1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.222222222, 0, 0.666666667, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0.5, 1, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, NA, 0.038461538, 1, 0, 0.052631579, 0.5, 0.333333333, 
    0, NA, 0, 0.236842105, 0.463414634, 0.266666667, 0.066666667, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.037037037, 0.5, 0.105263158, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 
    0.095238095, 0.125, 2, 0.475, 0.2, NA, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0.173913043, 
    0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    0.588235294, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0.1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0.111111111, 
    0.166666667, 0.666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857143, NA, 0.666666667, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 
    0.2, 0, 0.75, 0.333333333, NA, 0.25, 0, 0.625, NA, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.363636364, 0, NA, 0.25, 0, 0.105263158, 0, 0.166666667, 
    0, 0.5, 0.25, NA, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.181818182, 0.2, 0, 0, 
    0.285714286, 0, 0.066666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.181818182, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, NA, 0, 0.027777778, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0.368421053, 0.25, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, 0.2, 0.095238095, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.25, 0.666666667, 
    0.333333333, 0.222222222, 0.5, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0.5, NA, 0.2, 0, 0.05, 0.8, 0.4, NA, 0, 0.181818182, NA, 
    0, NA, NA, 0.25, 0.25, 0.125, NA, 0.333333333, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0.333333333, NA, 0.352941176, 0.4, 1, 
    0.214285714, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.285714286, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.318181818, 0.222222222, 0.111111111, 0.173913043, 
    0.333333333, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0.5, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.045454545, 
    1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0.5, 0.5, 0.222222222, 0, 0.666666667, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0.5, 1, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, NA, 0.038461538, 1, 0, 0.052631579, 0.5, 0.333333333, 
    0, NA, 0, 0.236842105, 0.463414634, 0.266666667, 0.066666667, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.037037037, 0.5, 0.105263158, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 
    0.095238095, 0.125, 2, 0.475, 0.2, NA, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0.173913043, 
    0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    0.588235294, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0.1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0.111111111, 
    0.166666667, 0.666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857143, NA, 0.666666667, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 
    0.2, 0, 0.75, 0.333333333, NA, 0.25, 0, 0.625, NA, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.363636364, 0, NA, 0.25, 0, 0.105263158, 0, 0.166666667, 
    0, 0.5, 0.25, NA, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.181818182, 0.2, 0, 0, 
    0.285714286, 0, 0.066666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.181818182, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, NA, 0, 0.027777778, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0.368421053, 0.25, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, 0.2, 0.095238095, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.25, 0.666666667, 
    0.333333333, 0.222222222, 0.5, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0.5, NA, 0.2, 0, 0.05, 0.8, 0.4, NA, 0, 0.181818182, NA, 
    0, NA, NA, 0.25, 0.25, 0.125, NA, 0.333333333, 0, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0), moanratio = c(NA, 0, NA, 0.117647059, 0.1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.095238095, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.266666667, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.055555556, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0.2, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.666666667, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.285714286, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0.166666667, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.090909091, 0.166666667, 
    NA, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.083333333, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0.5, 
    0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.027777778, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111, 
    0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.022222222, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
    0, 0, 0.142857143, NA, 0, 0.166666667, 0.1, NA, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.111111111, 0, 0.090909091, 
    0, 0, NA, 0.090909091, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857143, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, NA, 0, 0.166666667, 0, NA, 0, 0.142857143, 0, 0.071428571, 
    0.125, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.083333333, 
    0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0.055555556, 0.125, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 
    0, 0, 0.055555556, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076923077, 0.083333333, 
    0.076923077, 0, 0.076923077, NA, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 
    0, 0, 0.058823529, 0, 0.333333333, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, NA, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, NA, 0, 0, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076923077, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071428571, 
    0.058823529, NA, 0.076923077, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.076923077, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.2, 0.25, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
    0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.5, 
    0, 0.111111111, 0, 0, 0, 0.043478261, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.2, 
    0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.125, 0, 0, 0.066666667, NA, 0, 
    NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.166666667, NA, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111111111, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.142857143, NA, 0.5, 0.666666667, 
    0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, NA, 1.25, 0.4, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0.083333333, 0.023255814, 0.047619048, 0, 0.111111111, 
    0.545454545, 0, 0.208333333, 0.090909091, 0.142857143, 0, 
    0, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.055555556, 
    0, NA, 0, 0.083333333, 0.083333333, 0, 0, 0.03125, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.055555556, 0, NA, 0, 0.037037037, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.041666667, 
    0, 0, 0.333333333, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.052631579, 0.052631579, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0.016393443, 
    0.054054054, 0.066666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.034482759, NA, 0.024390244, 
    0, 0.12, 0.090909091, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.041666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.058823529, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.042553191, 
    0, 0.066666667, 0.076923077, 0, 0, 0.066666667, 0, 0, 0.076923077, 
    0.054054054, NA, 0.153846154, 0, 0.027777778, 0.2, 0, 0.173913043, 
    0.1875, 0.181818182, 0.142857143, 0.125, 0.111111111, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.05, 0, 0.1, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0.125, 
    0, NA, 0.045454545, NA, 0.25, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.111111111, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.136363636, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333, 
    0, 0.125, 0, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, NA, 0, 0, 0.076923077, 0, NA, 0.133333333, 0.5, 0, 0.083333333, 
    0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.066666667, 0.125, NA, NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625, 
    0.166666667, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0.1, 0, 0.076923077, 0.076923077, 
    0.117647059, 0, 0, 0.166666667, 0.5, 0, 0, NA, 0.090909091, 
    0, 0.2, 0.166666667, 0, 0, 0.090909091, 0.08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076923077, 0.142857143, 0, 
    0.230769231, 0.04, 0.071428571, 0, 0.083333333, 0.132075472, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, 0.034482759, 0.533333333, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 
    NA, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.066666667, 0.071428571, 0, 0.125, 0.04, 0.083333333, 0, 
    NA, 0.071428571, 0.181818182, 0, 0.238095238, 0, 0, 0.066666667, 
    0.117647059, 0, NA, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0.052631579, 
    0.130434783, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0), nndistance = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2", 
    "3.5", "5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("focal", "sexnn", 
"groomingratio", "moanratio", "nndistance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1110L))
```

And this code:

```
library(geepack)
library(tweedie)
library(statmod)

gee=geeglm(moanratio~groomingratio + sexnn + nndistance, id=focal, family=tweedie(var.power=1.5, link.power=0), corstr="ex", data=na.omit(ldata))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in geese.fit(xx, yy, id, offset, soffset, w, waves = waves, zsca,  : 
  mean.link invalid.
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to implement a GEE model in R with a Tweedie distribution.